# Errors in kmeans

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have the following type of data,

```
total = 
        0         0
        0         0          
        1.0000    1.0000
        0.0230    0.0483
        0.0002    0.0001
```

I extracted this data from the histograms of the two DICOM images, using

```
img1 = imhist(X);
img2 = imhist(Y);
total = [img1,img2];
```

I am trying to apply the kmeans on it as

```
 nClusters = 3;

 results = kmeans(total, nClusters);
```

But it shows the error on the kmeans line, Please suggest me something how should I get over with this.

Here is the error I am facing

```
Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'kmeans'
```

Comment: Can not reproduce an error using the example values.

Comment: @Matt But it is showing, I have been trying it adding more data and reducing and increasing number of clusters but still same.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are you sure that total is like you wrote because I cannot reproduce the error neither. Please write the error message. Do you have statistics toolbox ?

Comment: @oro777 I have updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Check if you have installed the Statistics Toolbox, you can type 'ver' in the console to see the installed toolboxes.

Comment: @oro777 I can't see any tool installed with this name, how do I install it?

Comment: You need to own the toolbox, you have to check your license. If your license allows it, you can download it from your MathWorks account else you need to purchase the toolbox. If you only need kmeans, you can search for it in Matlab central, there are some equivalent functions there.

Comment: @oro777 thank you. how do I mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: I copied my comment as an answer for more clarity on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to own the toolbox, you have to check your license. If your license allows it, you can download it from your MathWorks account else you need to purchase the toolbox. If you only need kmeans, you can search for it in Matlab Central, there are some equivalent functions there.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a data input problem that doesn't have sufficient numbers to allow for 3 clusters or the data is so tightly grouped that many of the requested 3 are empty even if appears to be sufficient DOF overall.

Comment: what is the solution to it?

Comment: I added more data but still same error. Also tried reducing and increasing the number of clusters